# Make it easier to enter Unicode chess symbols in questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

The following chess symbols are available in Unicode:

```
white chess king    ♔   U+2654
white chess queen   ♕   U+2655
white chess rook    ♖   U+2656
white chess bishop  ♗   U+2657
white chess knight  ♘   U+2658
white chess pawn    ♙   U+2659
black chess king    ♚   U+265A
black chess queen   ♛   U+265B
black chess rook    ♜   U+265C
black chess bishop  ♝   U+265D
black chess knight  ♞   U+265E
black chess pawn    ♟   U+265F
```

It would be useful to have an easy way of entering these on chess.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, though at this point the real challenge the community faces is growing. Has the lack of an easy way to use the unicode chess symbols stopped you from answering or asking questions on the main site?

Comment: @blunders I never said it did.

Answer (score 4):

I would be against the use of Unicode chess symbols for the following reasons:

- Human Readability: In my opinion, the unicode chess symbols are hard to read.
- Search Engine Readability: Google does not appear to index Unicode chess symbols, and Google is a huge source of traffic for SE websites